# JPA, EclipseLink and Android

Tags: android, jpa, persistence, eclipselink

I built a `JAVA` application for personal use, that makes the persistence with `JPA` and `EclipseLink`.
I'm making a equal for `android`. I would like to synchronize data via `Dropbox`.
Is there JPA and EclipseLink for android? I have not found anything about this.
What alternarivas there?

Comment: I add the use of the application, I do not know if it provides something.
It is to take "notes" that are important to me and store them encrypted. 
and be able to see them from the computer and phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run almost anything which is pura java on android (with some minor exclusions ), but this does not mean that you should.  Hibernate ( which is implementing JPA )  can be run on android, but your application willbe  too heavy.   Your handset is not  heavy server system.

I would propose to store data locally serialized to JSON and exchange  JSON data files via dropbox ( but of course I do not know anything about your use case to make better proposals )

Answer (score 1):

JPA implementations such as EclispeLink and Hibernate are too heavy for android. There are some light-weight ORM tools, but they are not implementing JPA specification. [Cmobilecom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com) is a new light-weight JPA implementation for both Java and Android. Its size is about 380K.

If you want to migrate your java application to android, simply
add the following gradle dependencies to your project:

Android:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-android:${version}@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }

    annotationProcessor "com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-processor:$version"
}
```

You can use [Cmobilecom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com) for java applications or server side (JDBC) too:

```
dependencies {
    implementation "com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-jdbc:$version"

    // annotation processor: generate static metamodel
    compileOnly "com.cmobilecom:cmobilecom-jpa-processor:$version"
}
```

Disclaimer: I am a developer of [Cmobilecom JPA](http://cmobilecom.com).